# How to find all items in table that don't have a certain text in column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table iminvbin_sql.. This table has columns item_no, loc, bin_no.  Each item number should have 4 bins in location 2.  how do I find all the items that do not have these four bins in loc 2?

I tried

```
select item_no from iminvbin_sql where bin_no not in('910SHIP','910STAGE','910PROD','1') AND loc = 2
```

but that didn't work.

```
itemno loc  bin

0       2    1 
0       2    910PROD
0       2    910SHIP
0       2    910STAGE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
select item_no
from iminvbin_sql
where bin_no in ('910SHIP', '901STAGE', '910PROD', '1') and
      loc = 2
group by item_no
having count(distinct bin_no) <> 4;
```

This will check that all four of those values are in the bins.  If you want to verify that these four values are in the bins *and* no other values are, you can test for this as well:

```
select item_no
from iminvbin_sql
where loc = 2
group by item_no
having count(distinct bin_no) <> 4 or
       count(distinct case when bin_no in ('910SHIP', '901STAGE', '910PROD', '1') then bin_no end) <> 4 or
       count(*) <> 4;
```

EDIT:

In response to Bohemian's comment, the following should get all items that are not fully populated:

```
select item_no
from iminvbin_sql
group by item_no
having count(distinct case when loc = 2 then bin_no end) <> 4 or
       count(distinct case when loc = 2 then bin_no in ('910SHIP', '901STAGE', '910PROD', '1') then bin_no end) <> 4 or
       sum(case when loc = 2 then 1 else 0 end) <> 4;
```

Comment: at first thought this too, but your first query won't return items that have *none* of the listed bins

Comment: @Bohemian . . . That is a good point, and important in this case where the goal is to find the "bad" items rather than the "good" ones.  Not having any such rows seems to be "badness".

Comment: when I run these it returns 27000 rows.  I checked like 10 of them and they all had the correct bins

Comment: At first these didn't work... But then I noticed the '901STAGE' should be 910STage.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use a `group by` with a `having` clause to determine if *all* bins are not there:

```
select item_no
from iminvbin_sql
group by item_no
having sum(case when loc = 2 and bin_no in ('910SHIP','901STAGE','910PROD','1') then 1 end) < 4
```

The important point with this query is that by moving the condtions into the `case`, it will find items that have none any of the listed bins or even items that have no data for `loc = 2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  itemno
FROM
  iminvbin_sql
WHERE
  loc = 2
GROUP BY
  itemno
HAVING
  4 <> SUM(CASE WHEN bin IN ('910SHIP','901STAGE','910PROD','1') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```